# Lua - Add physics to newSprite

Tags: debugging, lua, coronasdk

I am working on a 2d platformer for a class, but I can't get the physics to work with my sprite sheet.
I get the error message:

```
game.lua:82: ERROR: table expected. If this is a function call, you might have used '.' instead of ':'
```

I tried changing the line to a ':' instead of '.' but it still does not work. Here is my program code:

```
sequenceData = {
    {name = "running", frames={6,7,8,9,10}, time = 500, loopCount = 1},
    {name = "jump", framse={5}}
}
characterSheet = graphics.newImageSheet("/images/agent.png", {sheetContentWidth = 306, sheetContentHeight = 53}) 
character = display.newSprite(characterSheet, sequenceData)
--character = display.newImage( "/images/agentSingle.png", 50, 50 )

--this is line 82 \/
physics.addBody(character, "dynamic", { density=1.0, friction=0.5, bounce=0.0 })
```

I am confused though, because if I use a newImage instead of newSprite (the commented out line) it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

First check whether your sprite is created and animation is playing. And then add to the physics.

```
 local dummySprite = require("objects.dummySprite")
   local dummySheet = graphics.newImageSheet(_G.IMAGEPATH.."DummySprite.png", dummySprite:getSheet())

local playerGroup = display.newGroup()

local sequenceData =
{
    { name="jumping", start=51, count=9, time=1000, loopCount=0 }
}

local player = display.newSprite(playerGroup, dummySheet, sequenceData)
player:setSequence("jumping")
--player.xScale = .5; player.yScale = .5 (tried scaling as well, same poor results)     
player.width = 32; player.height = 32
player:setReferencePoint(display.c)
player.x = x; player.y = y; player.name = name

--Add Physics
physics.addBody(player, "static", { friction=friction, density=density, bounce=bounce, filter=_G.FILTER_PLAYER })
```